# What do double quotes in a Java expression mean?

Tags: java, expression, quotes

What do double quotes mean in a Java expression?

I have:

```
"2 + 2" + 3 + 4

"hello 34" + 2 * 4

1 + ""
```

Can someone explain how these expressions are evaluated, and what the purpose of the last one is?

Comment: I am voting to reopen this because 1) this is (IMO) a useful and legitimate question (after editing), 2) it is being used as a dup target, and 3) there are more useful things that could be said in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anything inside `" "` will become `String`. and `string` + `Int` = `String` .for example,

```
"2 + 2" + 3 + 4
```

you will get `2 + 234`

in your question,

```
"2 + 2" + 3 + 4 +"hello 34" + 2 * 4 //i added '+' between '4' and 'hello' since there is an error in expression
```

will be evaluated like this:

```
1. output = "2 + 2" + 3 + 4 +"hello 34" + 2 * 4
2. output = "2 + 2" + 3 + 4 +"hello 34" + 8 //operation '*' evaluated first
3. output = "2 + 23" + 4 +"hello 34" + 8
4. output = "2 + 234" +"hello 34" + 8
5. output = "2 + 234hello 34" + 8
6. output = "2 + 234hello 348"
```

Comment: Ah, so the double quote turns it into a string making the + operator do concatenation instead of arithmetic. Thanks for the clarification. A follow up question if you don't mind, say I changed to operator, for example : "2 + 2" + 3 * 4, would any arithmetic have to be carried out?

Comment: "2 + 2" + 3 * 4 will give you 2 + 212 since operation * evaluated first

Comment: Thank you for the help. I get nervous asking about asking questions on this site because of how hostile it seems. Thanks though, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator has two meanings in Java.

- When both operands are numeric<sup>1</sup>, it means arithmetic addition.
- When either operand has type `String`, it means string concatenation.

In the string concatenation case, a non-string argument is first to a string.  The process is called *string conversion* and is specified in [JLS 5.11.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1).  The procedure is as follows:

- A primitive type is converted to a string *as if* it was boxed, and the `toString()` was called on the boxed value.
- A `null` is converted to the string `"null"`.
- Any other reference type is converted by calling its `toString()`.

The complete semantics of `+` concatenation are specified in [JLS 15.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1).

---

[@Baby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20390626/139985) explains how this works for the first example in the Question, and the second example is similar.  (Note that `*` has a higher precedence than `+` so `2 * 4` is evaluated as a multiplication and `8` is then used in the concatenation.)

The third example is a common Java idiom for converting a number to a `String`.  Thus

```
  1 + "" -> "1"        // equivalent to Integer.toString(1)
  1.0 + "" -> "1.0"    // equivalent to Double.toString(1.0)
```

On the face of it, the versions in comments *should be* more efficient.  Concatenating with `""` would *appear* to be performing an unnecessary concatenation.  However, if you read the wording of the spec carefully, it is apparent that the Java compilers are *permitted* to optimize the first form to the second.  It is my understanding that they do ... in recent versions of Java.

Many people consider the `... + ""` idiom to be bad practice.  However it is common enough that you need to recognize it when you encounter it.

---

<sup>1 - In this context, this means any integral or floating point primitive type, or any of the matching wrapper types.  The complete set is `byte`, `short`, `char`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `java.lang.Byte`, `java.lang.Short`, `java.lang.Character`, `java.lang.Integer`, `java.lang.Long`, `java.lang.Float`, and `java.lang.Double`.</sup>